# POSIX find all local files

Tags: find, posix

I'm trying to write a cross-platform command line that will find all local files on a file system.

My intention is to use the `find` command, using only POSIX parameters.  Is there a way to skip files on remote filesystems, while restricted to only POSIX commands, and no programming?

My current command line is

```
find -type f -print
```

but that obviously lists every regular file, not just local ones.

I am aware of the `-local` flag, but as far as I can tell, it's not POSIX or otherwise part of a cross-platform standard.  `locate` doesn't appear to be cross-platform either.  I don't think the `-xdev` flag is what I'm looking for, either, as I want to search across all locally mounted file systems - if `/` and `/home` are both local, and I run `find / -xdev -print`, `find` should skip `/home` (unless I'm misunderstanding stuff).

For what it's worth, the following URLs have been useful resources...

- http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1/find/
- http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Unix/FindCmd.htm

Comment: Your observation about `-xdev` is correct. Have you looked at (ab-)using find's `-fstype` option at all?

Comment: @Anthon: Yes, I did take a quick look, but <code>-fstype</code> seems very much like rici's suggestion, and would require enumerating all expected file system types in advance...  I'm hoping for something more automated :)

Comment: I don't know if it would help, but you can use `-exec` to run any command as a test (and proceed with the `find` primaries or not, based on its exit status).  If you have a POSIX command which will return 0 if and only if it's run on a local file, you could make use of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is any way to determine whether a filesystem is remote or local using only POSIX interfaces. POSIX doesn't even mandate a `mount` command, and all references to file systems, as far as I know, are replete with the words "implementation-defined".

The `-local` primary to the `find` command is not much help, since it is only available on Solaris, and it depends on the existence of a configuration file which lists remote filesystem types.

POSIX does mandate a `df` command and requires a specific output format if that command is used with the `-P` flag; in that format, there are six space-separated fields, of which the first is the "name of the file system, in an implementation-defined format" and the last is the mount point.

What you need is a list of all the mount points corresponding to local filesystems. Here, I think you're going to have to fall back to a heuristic; which is to exclude filesystem names which "look like" remote filesystems. Some examples:

```
//...     CIFS (Samba)
host:...  NFS
/afs      AFS
```

That's not an exhaustive list, and it comes completely without guarantees.

If you then filter those lines out of the output of `df` and then remove the first five columns, you could then feed the list to the `find` command with the `-xdev` primary.

Even if that sounds plausible, there is actually no guarantee that a filesystem is actually "mounted" (see AFS) or that a filesystem is either entirely local or entirely remote (a fuse-based filesystem can arbitrarily redirect individual files). So proceed with caution, is my advice.

Answer (score 0):

That `-xdev` works but maybe not how you'd like, i.e. as stated in `POSIX` `find` [man](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47): `find -xdev` runs until FS with different`Device ID` (could be inspected with `stat` utility or `stat()` systemcall) is encountered:

e.g. `linux`:

```bsh
# stat /home/foo
  File: `/home/foo'
    . . .
Device: fd02h/64770d
  . . .
```

```bsh
 # stat /boot/foo
  File: `/boot/foo'
  . . . 
Device: 801h/2049d   
  . . .
```

Let's find it with `-xdev`:

```bsh
# find / -xdev -name foo -print
#
```

without:

```bsh
# find / -name foo -print
/home/foo
/boot/foo
```

Inspecting `Device ID` on `Solaris`:

```bsh
# truss -t lstat64 -v lstat64 ls /foo
lstat64("/foo", 0xFFBFFC48)
    d=0x02580000 . . .
```

```bsh
# truss -t lstat64 -v lstat64 ls /etc/foo
lstat64("/etc/foo", 0xFFBFFB88)
    d=0x02580000 . . .
```

```bsh
# truss -t lstat64 -v lstat64 ls /opt/foo
lstat64("/opt/foo", 0xFFBFFC48)
    d=0x02580004 . . .
```